# Niddah and wound

Tags: halacha, niddah, blood

If someone is bleeding from their "region" and it is 100% for sure from a wound and NOT from menstruation, does it render them niddah and thus require them to restart their counting?

Comment: See Yoreh Deah 187:5-6

Comment: can you help me out and translate it for me? I don't know hebrew well enough yet :(

Comment: You should not rely on an Internet forum to answer nida questions, this is far too serious, detailed and "visual" to be able to do this online. You can ask where to find a rav who can help questions if you do not have one already. Also, in some cases, the right rav will detect a medical issue and refer you to a doctor with specific instructions - again not something you want online strangers to help with. Kind regards.

Comment: If you need help translating Hebrew Torah learning into English or you have the practical need to find a Rabbi for a real matter in your area, you can ask me for help at Davidariel25@gmail.com